# malloc: *** mmap(size=24576) failed (error code=12) error: can't allocate region - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I get this error on my iPod 4G when I navigate through my app for some time, And the entire screen gets white OR the app Hangs and then I have to Restart the app.

`**malloc: *** mmap(size=24576) failed (error code=12)

*** error: can't allocate region

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug**`

I know that  **error code=12**  generally means Memory Issues, but **I have used ARC for my app.**

Same error occurs when I click multiple buttons in the app in fast succession.

I did google for this issue but couldn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running out of memory. Place a simple NSLog statement in your `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method and see if that fires. Also try running Instruments to check and find any source of excess memory consumption in your app. While ARC is helpful and avoids a lot of manual intervention, it ***does not*** ensure that you'll never run out of memory.

Try reading through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) regarding debugging malloc related stuff.

Comment: thanks for the instant rply.. but Analyze doesn't give me any leaks in my code.. And if I use Instruments I get only one leak..  **mallo192 Bytes CFNetwork createCanonicalURL**

Comment: @objc_developer Checking for leaks is not that relevant anymore.  ARC takes care of most of the leaks for you.  Your problem is holding onto references to objects so that they are not technically leaks but they can't be deallocated either.

Comment: It seems that you allocate too many objects. Leaks occurs when you lost track of an unused item without releasing it (here ARC will help you). But for example, if you keep all your object with strong property, you won't have leak, but serious allocation issue.

Comment: @KIDdAe then how do I solve this issue you just mentioned.??  Because that may be the case in my issue..  I guess I'll have to nil those objects by  **self.object = nil;**  which I declared using **Strong**

Comment: Like Bourne told you, you can handle those issues in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and remove objects that you don't need at the moment. Or in a more general way, remove what you can easily take back when you will need it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with ARC, objects tend to be put into the autorelease pool, so whilst you may have done with an object and it's gone out of scope or it;s pointers have been nilled, it may still be hanging around till the end of the run loop.

If you have a big activity, that creates a lot of temporary objects, then that can fill memory.

One solution is to wrap code with temporary objects in a `@autoreleasepool{ }` block.

Another is to split the activity into multiple parts, and run them in separate iterations of the runloop. GCD or `performSelector:after:0` can help here.